# Pandas groupby().sum() is not ignoring None/empty/np.nan values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am facing a weird problem with Pandas `groupby().sum()` together.

I have a DF with 2 category columns and 3 `numeric/float` value columns - value columns have `None`s as shown below:

```
  cat_1 cat_2  val_1  val_2  val_3
0     b     z    0.1    NaN    NaN
1     b     x    0.1    NaN    NaN
2     c     y    0.1    1.0    NaN
3     c     z    0.1    NaN    NaN
4     c     x    0.1    1.0    NaN
```

I want to **group-by** `cat_1` and then **sum** the value columns: `val_1`, `val_2` and `val_3` per category.

This is what the final aggregation should look like:

```
  cat_1  val_1  val_2  val_3
0     b    0.2    NaN    NaN
1     c    0.3    2.0    NaN
```

**Problem:** is that when I do `df.groupby(["cat_1"], as_index=False).sum()`, I get `0.0` for categories where all values are `None/null`:

```
  cat_1  val_1  val_2  val_3
0     b    0.2    0.0    0.0
1     c    0.3    2.0    0.0
```

How can I fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: `min_count=1` should work https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

Comment: Yes, that is true. It does work with that. However, isn't there a better, more direct, way of doing it?

Comment: `skipna=False` would work I guess, however it is not implemented on GroupBy.sum..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no direct way of doing it like via `DataFrame.sum(skipna=False)` but it is not implemented for groupby-sum. However, as [ScootCork](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4700327/scootcork) mentioned, the required behaviour can be achieved using: `groupby().sum(min_count=1)` - [from documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html).